# Multiple time series regression

Tags: regression, time-series

I'm looking for techniques to do regression of multiple time series on another time series. In specific 3 time series on 1 time series. Where the regression model would contain lagged values of the 3 time series.

I have read that this would be possible with dynamic models but it seems that I cannot find any good resources about this framework.

Could anyone provide me any feedback on how I can best do this?
I was also wondering if this would be possible with a VAR-model?

Comment: This is very abstract. Could you provide some details?